# Hex numbers appear backwards in javascript implementation of Java Long

Tags: java, javascript, hex, long-integer

As javascript has no native Long type (as Java does), I'm currently using [this](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_math_Long.html) class, which is supposed to emulate Java's Long type.  However, I'm getting strange output.

- Java Long1: 3837363534333231, JS Long1: 3132333435363738
- Java Long2: 3635343332313039, JS Long2: 3930313233343536

And when I XOR them together: I get:

- JavaXor: e02020606020208, JSXor: 80202060602020e

These values are obtained by calling:

- Java:  Long.toHexString(var);
- JS: Long.toString(16) (this is a method of the goog.math.Long class)

You'll notice the the JS representations (1 and 2) appear backwards, shifting every two characters (as hex represents 2 chars, when compared to their Java equivalents.  The XOR result is a bit different, in that it's backwards, but character-for-characters.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this normal behaviour? Can anyone guess why this might be happening?

Comment: It appears that one is little endian and the other is big endian.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - sounds reasonable - I'll look into it.

Comment: Re: "The XOR result is a bit different, in that it's backwards, but character-for-characters": Nah, it's still byte-by-byte (hex-pair-by-hex-pair) backwards: one is `0e02020606020208`, the other is `080202060602020e`. It's just that the leading `0` is stripped in both cases, making this less obvious.